# How do I retrieve information from file_get_contents(php://input)?

Tags: php, post, file-get-contents

I am trying to fix a callbackurl and in the old system I could simply use a `$_POST['order_id']` when trying to retrieve the data. Unfortunately that no longer seems to be possible.

The new system uses this line of code:

```
$request_body = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

According to the technical data sheet the `order_id` is now simply called `id`, but how do I use `$request_body` to retrieve it? Something like `$request_body['id']` ?

Comment: why don't you `var_dump` the `$request_body` to see what contains?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of data you send to server? Probably the form is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded, so you can use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function to parse query string.

`php://input` contains the raw data after request HTTP headers.

```
$request_body = file_get_contents("php://input");

$data = array();

parse_str($request_body, $data);

var_dump($data);
```

If you send JSON for example, you can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: Id tried to do this: $request_body = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = array();
parse_str($request_body, $data);
$getmyid = $data['id']; But unfortunately nothing was retrieved. Could you show me what you mean by json_decode?

Comment: I tried to save the $request_body directly to my database, and finally something happened. It's a wealth of data in the format of {"id":8683104,"order_id":"1853926"," etc. etc.}. This I can work with I think.

Comment: It seems like your data is stored in JSON. You can use `$data = json_decode($request_body, true);` to get an associative array based on your JSON.